# Count up timer in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

How to you make a count up timer that still goes on in the background ? I want it to show seconds, minutes, hours, days, months. I only want to reset it when I click reset.

Thank you!

Comment: please share you search ...

Answer (score 0):

Familiarize yourself with this sample program.

The system clock does what you're assuming.
we just refer to it.

Counting months is difficult. Because the number of days in a month is either 28, 29, 30, or 31.

popup.js

```js
const elmCounter = document.getElementById("counter");
const elmReset = document.getElementById("reset");

let lastTime = localStorage["lastTime"];
if (lastTime == null) {
  lastTime = new Date();
  localStorage["lastTime"] = lastTime;
}
else {
  lastTime = new Date(lastTime);
}

counter();

elmReset.onclick = () => {
  lastTime = new Date();
  localStorage["lastTime"] = lastTime;
};

async function counter() {
  while (1) {
    const nowTime = new Date();
    let diffTime = nowTime.getTime() - lastTime.getTime();
    diffTime /= 1000;
    diffTime = Math.floor(diffTime);
    const day = Math.floor(diffTime / (24 * 60 * 60));
    diffTime -= day * 24 * 60 * 60;
    const hour = Math.floor(diffTime / (60 * 60));
    diffTime -= hour * 60 * 60;
    const min = Math.floor(diffTime / 60)
    const sec = diffTime % 60
    elmCounter.innerText = day + "," + hour + "," + min + "," + sec;
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
  }
}
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      font-size: xx-large;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="min-width:250px;min-height:100px">
  <div id="counter"></div><br>
  <input type="button" id="reset" value="reset">
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```