# Making Chrome Web Browser Extension Work in Background 2022

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension, manifest.json

I started creating a web browser extension for chromium, manifest v3 (Pomodoro timer) and started coding as it was a standard web page. Everything was working fine till I keep the popup open and timer works fine and as intended. But, not when I close the popup. the timer doesn't work and the process of timer ends. So I came across this background.js stuff and I don't have any idea how to migrate my "popup.js" to say "background.js" for making it run in the background. Basically, what will be the code changes.

*manfiest.json*

```
{
    "name": "HyperFocused⚡",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "128": "icons/3.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/3.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "minimum_chrome_version": "93",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    }
}
```

**I'm pretty new to web-dev and javascript so don't mind the coding practice. Not at all clean code. I just wanted to get the work done.**

*popup.js*

```
var timerStarted = false;
var playing = true;
var minutes = 0; //Default Minutes
var seconds = 25; //Default Seconds


let pomoMin; //Pomodoro Minutes
let pomoSec; //Pomodoro Seconds
var myTime;

const touchTimerElement = document.getElementById('touchTimer');
const startStopTimerElement = document.getElementById('startStopTimer');

function resetTime() {
    pomoMin = minutes;
    pomoSec = seconds;
}

function startStopText() {
    startStopTimerElement.innerHTML = timerStarted ? "STOP" : "START";
}

function setTimerTime() {
    touchTimerElement.innerHTML =
        `${pomoMin}`.padStart(2, '0') + ':' + `${pomoSec}`.padStart(2, '0');
}

function reset() {
    clearInterval(myTime);
    resetTime();
    playing = true;
    setTimerTime();
}

function countdownTimer() {
    if (!playing) return;
    if (pomoMin >= 0) {

        setTimerTime();

        pomoSec--;


        if (pomoSec == -1) {
            pomoSec = 59;
            pomoMin--;
        }


    }
    else {
        // window.open(
        //     // Just use the full URL if you need to open an external page
        //     // url: chrome.runtime.getURL("google.com")
        //     "breaktime.html", "_blank"
        // );
        reset();
        timerStarted = false;
        startStopText();
    }
}

startStopTimerElement.onclick = function () {


    if (!timerStarted) {
        //start the timer;
        countdownTimer();
        myTime = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
    }
    else {
        reset();
    }
    timerStarted = !timerStarted;
    startStopText();

}


//pomoSec
touchTimerElement.onclick = function () {
    if (timerStarted) playing = !playing;
}

startStopText();
resetTime();
setTimerTime();
```

*popup.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>HyperFocused</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="title">
        hyper<span class="fcsd">focused</span>
    </div>
    <!-- <button class="timerModes" value="Work Mode">Hello</button> -->
    <div id="touchTimer" class="timer">
    </div>
    <div id="startStopTimer" class="stopButton">
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It can be achieved without background using LocalStorage or chrome.storage. 
[count-up-timer-in-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74132700/count-up-timer-in-chrome-extension/74138087#74138087)

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I understood your point but what I require is to perform "certain actions" automatically depending on the time left of the countdown. With your method I will get the correct time remaining but for that I will have to keep on looking at the timer and open the popup again!

Comment: You can use chrome.alarms.
Set alarms in popup, listen for alarms in background, and call window.open when it fires.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Norio Yamamoto comment, it is important to consider the following points:

- the popup code (html+js) only lives for the time of the popup being
  displayed. So once the popup is closed, the JavaScript context is gone :
  all timers are cleared, all variables are destroyed, etc.
- the background page in Manifest v3 is not a background page: it's a service
  Worker. There are some important differences between the two as a service
  worker can become inactive (timeouts are destroyed too). But you can attach
  listeners like on `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener` to be notified when
  an alarm is triggered. This will wake up the service
  worker and run the attached listener.

So, in your case, you can use the `chrome.alarms.create()` API to create an
alarm that will be triggered whenever you want. Then, in the service worker,
you can attach a listener to the `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener` event to
be notified when the alarm is triggered by matching its name.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have taken some other approach for going through this by following some similar github projects. If you could write some pseudo-code along with it for some other beginners like that would be really helpful for others who see this answer!

Comment: @PranjalChaplot Which approach did you take for information?